# Serverless spark job throwing an error while using shared VPC to connect on-prem storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless, google-nat-gateway

I am trying to run simple serverless spark(dataproc batch) job which reads object from on-prem ECS with shared VPC. I have open egress firewall in shared vpc to connect on-prem storage but I don't see that firewall rule is getting hit
There are very less resources available at the moment since this is a new product GA recently.

> Failed to initialize node
> gdpic-srvls-batch-fxxxx7-cxx6-4xxd-bxx6-6xxxxxx4-m: Timed out
> waiting for at least 1 worker(s) registered. This is often caused by
> firewall rules that prevent Spark workers from communicating with the
> master. Please review your network firewall rules and be sure they
> allow communication on all ports between all nodes. See
> https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/network for
> instructions. See output in: gs://gcs-object-xxxx

I tried looking into url provided but couldn't find much details.
If I have to setup NAT gateway with shared VPC project with my project how can I do?
Has anyone solved this problem already?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it means that there is no connectivity between internal IP addresses in your VPC. Adding firewall rule as shown in the linked doc, should help:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-internal-ingress \
  --network="network-name" \
  --source-ranges="subnetwork internal-IP ranges" \
  --direction="ingress" \
  --action="allow" \
  --rules="all"
```

Comment: Thanks @Igor, I already have egress rule in my shared VPC, do you suggest to create ingress there? If so I don't understand why it need it?

Comment: @JaysukhKalasariya It's needed because Spark executors need to talk (call in) to Spark driver (driver and executors use VPC internal IP addresses to communicate between each other), that's why both ingress and egress is required.

Comment: So this this FW rule has to be created in shared vpc right?

Comment: @JaysukhKalasariya yes, this is correct. Note that it's required only for internal VPC IPs, not public IPs.

Comment: Seems it is still troubling me when I apply this fw to shared vpc, something is restricting it in my project only.